# Cannot Resolve Symbol "exist" android 4.0

Tags: android, file, java-io

I have one problem. Please refer photo below:

[image: error]

Why his happen?
I need to check the file exist or not.
I already import Java.IO class.

Comment: why haven't you put `F.exists()` in brackets?

Comment: Anyone else notice how he's calling the `if F.exists()` within the scope of the class and not within a method?

Comment: @MikeBantegui i put in any method, class. still got this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check :

```
File file = new File("");

if (file.exists())
{
   // Do Something..
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(Your_file_Path);
        if(file.exists())      
        //Do somehting
        else
        // Do something else.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call exist within the scope of your function and not within the Class itself